# Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз?

Tags: wordpress

есть стандратный файл .htaccess для wordpress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Я добавил свой код
Дабы была автоматическая переадресация на https

```
Теперь код выглядит так
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Но сайт выдает ошибку Сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз после переноса WordPress и постоянно обновляется по себе. Как это можно исправить и за чего такое. Первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь , обычно такой код очень хорошо работал

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://site.ru/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`site` замените на свой домен

И не вписывайте никаких

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, заработало.

Comment: @Daniel qwaqwaqwa Пожалуйста